# How to insert query in ASP.net C# for crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report. I have successfully displayed reports to my crystal report page using Visual Studio's crystal report viewer. Now I am wondering how to insert queries with my crystal report so that I can filter what will be shown on my report. I am using C# and my sql is MS SQL. So far here's my code behind:

```
public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page     
{        
protected CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1;  
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{             
ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument(); 
reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("USER", "PA55", "SERVER1", "DBO1");
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;                   
}
```

How can I insert query here that for example I would like to print the report for specific dates or specific person.

Thank you and I will appreciate any input from you guys. Thanks for helping this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to write a stored procedure to flow the data into the crystal report.

After that, In crystal report, Choose Database->Database Expert, In that you need to select the corresponding stored procedure. In field explorer, you will see the stored procedure and its field. So you can place the fields where you need in the crystal report.

see this http://blog.softwaremedia.com/2012/01/set-up-your-database-and-create-a-report-in-crystal-reports/

Comment: thevan thank you. can you show some steps on how to do this. thank you.

Comment: can you show me some codes for that. I am to this one. thank you.